# CombinedPropertyError, Multiple Errors (DiscordJS 13)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have an issue with my commands, I'm using SlashCommandBuilder on DiscordJS v13. I can't be bothered to upgrade to v14. I don't know why, but Something below keeps giving me errors. The way the bot works is by connecting to a json files with values, and then fetching values from there when asked to through slash commands.

```
new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('buy')
  .setDescription('Get the price of a minion')
  .addStringOption(option => option.setName('minion').setDescription('Choose a minion').setRequired(true))
  .addStringOption(option => 
    option.setName('tier')
      .setDescription('Choose a tier')
      .setRequired(true)
      .addChoices([
          { name: 'Tier 11', value: 'Tier 11' },
          { name: 'Tier 12', value: 'Tier 12' }
      ])
  ),

new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('config')
  .setDescription('Set the price of a minion')
  .addStringOption(option => option.setName('minion').setDescription('Choose a minion').setRequired(true))
  .addStringOption(option => 
    option.setName('tier')
      .setDescription('Choose a tier')
      .setRequired(true)
      .addChoices([
          { name: 'Tier 11', value: 'Tier 11' },
          { name: 'Tier 12', value: 'Tier 12' }
      ])
  )
  .addNumberOption(option => option.setName('price').setDescription('Set the price').setRequired(true))
```

Error:

```
Bot is online!
C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:480
    return errors.length === 0 ? Result.ok(transformed) : Result.err(new CombinedPropertyError(errors));
                                                                     ^

CombinedPropertyError: Received one or more errors
    at _ArrayValidator.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:480:70)
    at _ArrayValidator.parse (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:216:88)
    at MixedClass.addChoices (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1763:22)
    at C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\bot.js:67:16
    at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2080:50)
    at MixedClass.addStringOption (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2052:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\bot.js:63:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:379:17) {
  errors: [
    [
      0,
      ValidationError: Expected the value to not be an array
          at _ObjectValidator.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1235:25)
          at _ObjectValidator.run (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:202:23)
          at _ArrayValidator.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:474:37)
          at _ArrayValidator.parse (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:216:88)
          at MixedClass.addChoices (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1763:22)
          at C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\bot.js:67:16
          at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2080:50)
          at MixedClass.addStringOption (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2052:17)
          at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\folder\bot.js:63:12)
          at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:632:26) {
        validator: 's.object(T)',
        given: [
          { name: 'Tier 11', value: 'Tier 11' },
          { name: 'Tier 12', value: 'Tier 12' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try not putting the argument of `addChoices` in square brackets. Your error says not to use an array at that point and there are plenty examples on the web how to add choices.

Comment: @CloudWatcher thank you so much, you helped me a lot with this, i'm very grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName('buy')
      .setDescription('Get the price of a minion')
      .addStringOption(option => option.setName('minion').setDescription('Choose a minion').setRequired(true))
      .addStringOption(option => 
            option.setName('tier')
            .setDescription('Choose a tier')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
                  { name: 'Tier 11', value: 'Tier 11' },
                  { name: 'Tier 12', value: 'Tier 12' }
            )
      )
```

You should have simply passed the arguments to addChoices not as an array)